# how to compare sympy datatypes

Tags: python, sympy, isinstance

I'm new to sympy and and would like to check if an argument is a sympy integer or of type mul. normally, you could do this using:

```
if ( isinstance(arg, int):
    // do stuff
```

I want to do something like:

```
if( isinstance(arg, Integer):
    // do stuff
```

or

```
if( isinstance(arg, sympy.core.mul.Mul):
    // do stuff
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does the above not work? I notice that you are not including the closing )s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is correct.

```
In [14]: from sympy import *

In [15]: a = 2*Symbol('x')

In [16]: isinstance(a, Mul)
Out[16]: True

In [17]: a = 2 + Symbol('x')

In [18]: isinstance(a, Add)
Out[18]: True
```